# TD Clickable without div or javascript

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site targeting older feature phone type mobiles that have limited css and html support. I have a table with a single row and two cells, that each contain a link. Ideally i would like both to be clickable. I tried a div solution but on some of the phone browsers I tested the text would dissapear, I assume because this is not entirely semantical.

Any sugggestions on how to accomplish this without using a div?

here is my html

```
<div><table style="width:100%;"><tbody><tr>

<td class="leftTd"><a href="link1"><Left</div></a></td>

<td class="rightTd"><a href="link2>Right</a></td>
</tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: Have you defined your `a` as a block-level element? Let's see your CSS.

Comment: You can't make a `<td>` clickable with `CSS`, you could however set the `CSS` of the `a` tag to `display:block`, this would allow you to add padding etc, and make it the full `width/height` of the `<td>`.

Comment: there's additional "<" character at the begining of leftTd text. remove it. If you realy need this char, use &lt; instead

Comment: You shouldn't use < before the Left text, use &lt; this way it thinks you're declaring a DOM element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup of the HTML you gave isn't valid. Here it is as valid markup

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftTd"><a href="link1">Left</a></td>
            <td class="rightTd"><a href="link2">Right</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

then if you make sure the a element are set to `display: block;` e.g

```
td a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually edited some of the html before posting it and hence the errors. Anyhow your solution worked and since you were the first to suggest it, marking it as the correct answer

Comment: I think @roko beat me to the answer to be honest.

Comment: Isn't the answer nearest to the top, the first one?

Comment: I think the answers are shown in a random order when no answer has been selected. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UwiPEBu/1/edit)***

```
td a {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Also fixed your HTML markup from errors:

```
<div>
 <table style="width:100%;">
     <tr>
      <td class="leftTd"><a href="link1">Left</a></td>
      <td class="rightTd"><a href="link2">Right</a></td>
     </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first link, you have a stray `<`.

In the second, you didn't close the quotes after `href`.

Old phones typically have browsers that won't grok broken HTML syntax very well, so I think this is the reason the links won't render.

I suggest you use an editor that checks HTML syntax, or at least some checker like the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

HTML4 event attributes

```
<table border="0" style="cursor:pointer" onMouseover="window.status='http://www.stackoverflow.com/'" onMouseout="window.status=''" onMouseup="window.location='http://www.stackoverflow.com/'" width="158" height="158" style="background-image: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png')">
    <tr>
        <td style="display:none;">This entire table is a link with no content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `targeting older feature phone type mobiles` ;-)